# Azure AD authentication and assigning roles to application users

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2017, azure-active-directory, user-roles

I am working on a .net core MVC Web application that is making use of Azure AD authentication with multi tenants enabled.Now I want to add custom application roles to my users. For that I added some "appRoles": to my azure WebApp's  manifest file.
But now how do I assign these application roles to my users ? 
I am using portal.azure.com, and I could not find any screens where I can actually assign these roles to my application users. Could you please let me know me where I can do this from the azure portal?or do I need any additional permissions from my AD team?if so what specific permissions ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could assign users with roles to application in `Enterprise applications` blade:

1. Click `Enterprise applications` blade , click `All applications` to find your application with app id or display name :
   [image]
2. Click that application , click `Users and groups` , you will get current assigned users and which role has been assigned :[image]
3. You could click add user and `Select Role` , you could select the roles you set in manifest file and assign to specific user :[image]

Comment: For those wondering, the enterprise application is the *service principal* created in the tenant that links back to the original application. Role assignments are always done on the service principals, no matter if it is a single- or multi-tenant app.

Comment: In the 2nd step above, when I click on users and groups, the "+Add User" option is showing as disabled. What specific permissions on my subscription/account are required for me to see the "+Add User" option enabled so that I can add users and go to step 3?

Comment: please try with Global administrator account .

Comment: @NanYu How can we re-assign the role of particular user back to "Default Access"? Currently I have assigned a particular role to the user but I want to change it to Default Access Role. I am only getting that option if I am deleting all the roles created by me. Is there a way we can change back to "Default Access" without deleting the created roles? Please help!!