# Azure AD: Why is everyone able to login to my app?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

While learning about Azure AD so I can eventually switch our applications to start using that, I noticed that any account that we have, seems to be able to login to the application...  I just have a web application on my local PC, and I added it to our Azure AD applications.  We have Azure AD syncing with our AD environment.  The application doesn't show up on myapps.microsoft.com, which is what I want to happen.  The issue is that when I try to login to the application by going to the URL, with a test account, that account is just able to login...  After one login, it shows up on that account's myapps page.  Why is it just allowing any account to log in?  I only have partial access on our Azure portal, and can't even manually give access to applications.  Is there some setting that I need to set to only allow access when it is specifically granted to the account?  I've been looking around for a while and watching a few videos, but I haven't seen this covered anywhere.

Comment: Are you using OpenIdConnect libraries in your code?  It sounds like what you're trying to do is restrict access to a particular group of users in the directory - correct?

Comment: I am using OpenIdConnect.  Yes, I'd like to restrict access to only those who were given access to the application, in Azure (and/or an AD group, in the future).  Right now we can't use AD Groups in our plan, but I've heard that out plan should be changing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Azure AD , if you want to restrict access to  particular users in the directory , you could try below ways :

1. Use [group claims](http://rickrainey.com/2015/02/13/using-group-claims-in-azure-active-directory/) in Azure AD . In your application , check the group claims in the authenticated user’s claims collection , restrict access base on your requirement .
2. Set `User assignment required?` setting( find the setting in `Enterprise applications`-->Your application -->`Properties`) to Yes, then users must first be assigned to your application before being able to access it . You could assign default access role to uses who can access your application . Click [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44815158/5751404) for how to assign role to user .

Comment: How can we re-assign the role of particular user back to "Default Access"? Currently I have assigned a particular role to the user but I want to change it to Default Access Role. I am only getting that option if I am deleting all the roles created by me. Is there a way we can change back to "Default Access" without deleting the created roles? Please help!!